# how can we avoid readonly of the excel file during the writestream to excel from c# , if the excel file is open?

Tags: c#, excel

during writing values to an excel from c#, at the same time the excel file is open it shows `the error that the file is in readonly` , so how can we able to avoid that error during write stream from c# to the Excel

```
    //Get all the sheets in the workbook
 mWorkSheets = mWorkBook.Worksheets;
 //Get the allready exists sheet
 mWSheet1 = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)mWorkSheets.get_Item("Sheet1");
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range = mWSheet1.UsedRange;

 int colCount = range.Columns.Count;


 int rowCount = range.Rows.Count+1;
 for (int index = 0; index < NoOfRecords; index++)
 {
     for (int j = 0; j < colCount; j++)
     {                       
         mWSheet1.Cells[(rowCount) + index, j + 1] ="'"+Convert.ToString(ResultsData.Rows[index][j].ToString());
     }
 }


 mWorkBook.SaveAs(path, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal,
 Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive,
 Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
 Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
mWorkBook.Close(Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to SAVEAS to a different file name, then delete the original file on successful save. Like open MySheet.XLSX and save MySheet_Updated.XLSX

```
 string newPath = path.Replace(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path),Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path)+"_Updated)";
 try{
    mWorkBook.SaveAs(newPath,Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal,Missing.Value,Missing.Value,Missing.Value,Missing.Value,Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive,Missing.Value,Missing.Value,Missing.Value,Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
   mWorkBook.Close(Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
   File.Delete(path); 
   File.Move(newPath,path);
   }
 catch(Exception e){
      Console.WriteLine(e.Message+"\n"+e.Source);
 }
```

Comment: it is contious writing if i use duplicate one how can i get the old rows of data from the orginal

Comment: You are saving the FILE, not the RANGE. So it's the same as though you opened a file, changed a range within it, and then hit SAVE AS. If you need to make another change 1) SAVE AS 2) DELETE original file 3) RENAME saved file to original file, 4) LOOP  -- see my edited answer above. Make backups in another directory, then test

Comment: in between the writing am opening then it will works or not?  mWSheet1.Cells[(rowCount) + index, j + 1] ="'"+Convert.ToString(ResultsData.Rows[index][j].ToString());     at this time am opening then how can i change the file directly or copy the file  it will directly goes to catch know..

Comment: What error are you getting? Either debug or take out the TRY/CATCH if you don't know how to debug - it will give you a specific error and line. Let me know that

Answer (score 0):

```
    public System.Data.DataTable CorruptedExcel(string path, string savedFile) {
    try
    {
        Missing missing = Missing.Value;
       Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application();

       Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(path, CorruptLoad: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlCorruptLoad.xlRepairFile);

        var connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;TypeGuessRows=0;ImportMixedTypes=Text\"";
        //var connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;IMEX=1;HDR=NO;TypeGuessRows=0;ImportMixedTypes=Text\""; ;
        using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
        {

            conn.Open();

            var sheets = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(System.Data.OleDb.OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });
            using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" + sheets.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString() + "] ";

                var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);



                adapter.Fill(dt);
            }
        }

        return dt;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new Exception("ReadingExcel: Excel file could not be read! Check filepath.\n"
            + e.Message + e.StackTrace);

    }
}
```